# Calendar - Unable to read recurring events

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am unable to get recurring events from google calandar. Can any one help me with this.

I have also used "Instances" table to get the recurring events but not. Can any one guide me how to fetch data from "Instances" table. It should be a great help for me.

I used following code to read events.

```
    Uri uri = CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[]{
            CalendarContract.Events._ID,
            CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,
            CalendarContract.Events.DTEND,
            CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY,
            CalendarContract.Events.TITLE,
            CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR,
            CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID,
            CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION,
            CalendarContract.Events.ORGANIZER,
            // If status = 2 it is cancelled by organizer
            CalendarContract.Events.STATUS,
            // If self attendee status  = 2 it is declined by user
            CalendarContract.Events.SELF_ATTENDEE_STATUS,
            CalendarContract.Events.RDATE,
            CalendarContract.Events.LAST_DATE
    };

    String[] calendarID;
    for (int i = 0; i < EmailId.size(); i++) {
        calendarID = new String[]{EmailId.get(i)};

       Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                CalendarContract.Instances.CALENDAR_ID + " = ?", calendarID, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Evnt e = new Evnt();

                e._id = c.getLong(0);

                e.startDate = "";
                e.startDate = getDate(c.getString(1));

                e.startTime = "";
                e.startTime = getTime(c.getString(1));


                e.endDate = "";
                e.endDate = getDate(c.getString(2));

                e.endTime = "";
                e.endTime = getTime(c.getString(2));

                e.all_day = c.getInt(3);
                e.title = c.getString(4);
                e.color = c.getInt(5);
                e.calendar_id = c.getLong(6);
                e.desc = c.getString(7);
                e.organizer = c.getString(8);

                e.nine = c.getString(9);
                e.ten = c.getString(10);
                e.eleven = c.getString(11);

                e.twelve = "";
                e.twelve = getDate(c.getString(12));

                ourEvents.add(e);

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @R2R Can u pls go through the question once again. I have added it in detail.

Comment: Earlier code was not showing

Comment: @R2R Sorry for the incovenience. I was editing it that time.